# Movable container in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have a container contains listview in it of some vehicles data when I scroll up only the data in the container is moving upwards I want to move the whole container. I dont want my UI like that, whole container should move upwards please help me out, and the other part is I have used shrink wrap and if my list have only one value it coming in the center of my screen and I dont want to behave like that.

```
new SingleChildScrollView(
  child: new Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0,top: 25.0,bottom: 25.0),
    child: new PhysicalModel(
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      color: Colors.white,
      shadowColor: Colors.grey,
      elevation: 0.0,
      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
      child:new ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: List.generate(
          this._allVehiclesData.length,
          (i) => new GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              _id = this._allVehiclesData[i]["vehicle"]["_id"];
              Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SingleVehicleDashboard(value:_id)));
            },
            child: new Card(
              elevation: 0.0,
              child:new Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:30.0,left: 30.0,right: 30.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            child: new Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                this._allVehiclesData[i]["vehicle"]["registration"] != null?
                                Text(
                                  this._allVehiclesData[i]["vehicle"]["registration"],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                    color: Color(0xFF454f63),
                                  ),
                                ):
                                Text(
                                  'New Vehicle',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                    color: Color(0xFF454f63),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                new Container(
                                  // padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0),
                                  child: status(i),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text('',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 8.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: new Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new IconTheme(
                                  data: new IconThemeData(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  child: Image.asset('assets/person.png'),
                                ),
                                new Container(
                                  child: new Text(this._allVehiclesData[i]["driver"]["fullname"],
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16.0,
                                      color: Color(0xFF78849e),
                                    ) ,
                                  )
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: new Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new Text(''),
                                new Container(
                                  child: new Text('',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 5.0,
                                    ) ,
                                  )
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: 
                            this._allVehiclesData[i]["temperature"] != "null" && this._allVehiclesData[i]["fuel"] != "null"?
                            new Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    new IconTheme(
                                      data: new IconThemeData(
                                        color: Color(0xFF78849e),
                                        size: 20.0,
                                      ),
                                      child: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                                    ),
                                    new Container(
                                      child: new Text((' '+this._allVehiclesData[i]["temperature"].toString()+'  C'),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 16.0,
                                          color: Color(0xFF78849e),
                                        ) ,
                                      )
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                new Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    new IconTheme(
                                      data: new IconThemeData(
                                        color: Color(0xFF78849e),
                                        size: 20.0,
                                      ),
                                      child: Icon(Icons.local_gas_station),
                                    ),
                                    new Container(
                                      child: new Text((this._allVehiclesData[i]["fuel"].toString()),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 16.0,
                                          color: Color(0xFF78849e),
                                        ) ,
                                      )
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ):
                            this._allVehiclesData[i]["temperature"] !="null"?
                            new Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    new IconTheme(
                                      data: new IconThemeData(
                                        color: Color(0xFF78849e),
                                      ),
                                      child: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                                    ),
                                    new Container(
                                      child: new Text((this._allVehiclesData[i]["temperature"].toString()+'  C'),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 16.0,
                                         color: Color(0xFF78849e),
                                        ) ,
                                      )
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ):
                            this._allVehiclesData[i]["fuel"] !="null"?
                            new Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    new IconTheme(
                                      data: new IconThemeData(
                                        color: Color(0xFF78849e),
                                      ),
                                      child: Icon(Icons.local_gas_station),
                                    ),
                                    new Container(
                                      child: new Text((this._allVehiclesData[i]["fuel"].toString()),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 16.0,
                                          color: Color(0xFF78849e),
                                        ) ,
                                      )
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ):new Text(''),
                          ),
                          new Text('',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 7.0)),
                          new Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new IconTheme(
                                data: new IconThemeData(
                                  color: Color(0xFF78849e),
                                ),
                                child: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                child: new Text((this._allVehiclesData[i]["address"] == null || 
                                  this._allVehiclesData[i]["address"] == 'Not determined') ? 
                                  "No data available" : this._allVehiclesData[i]["address"]["LongLabel"],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    letterSpacing: 0.5,
                                    height: 1.0,
                                    fontSize: 16.0,
                                    color: Color(0xFF78849e),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Text(''),
                          Divider(
                            height: 3.0,
                            color: Color(0xFFf4f4f6),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ),
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap Container in `SingleChildScrollView` & in ListView define -

```
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```

- Update you Code like this

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0, top: 25.0),
          child: new PhysicalModel(
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0), topRight: Radius.circular(20.0)),
            color: Colors.white,
            shadowColor: Colors.grey,
            elevation: 1.0,
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            child: new ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
               physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
.....
```

Comment: Say for suppose I have only one vehicle then the Data of that one vehicle will be in center of the screen but I should show from top right???. Help me out..

Comment: you want whole Container in case of 1 Car Data to show on top & not center.?

Comment: Yeah I want to show my container starts from top (after app bar) not at the center of the screen..

Comment: If I have more than 5 vehicles then the list is working as I want but If It have less than 3 then It displays in center of the screen

Comment: how about - Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter, ?

Comment: I tried you code its shows on top. With 25px Padding

Comment: what is your Parent of SingleChildScrollView ? Mine was Scaffold Body

Comment: I changed padding but still it works the same and my parent is a dynamic variable because I'm using them in TabBar  like all, moving , idle and parked Im storing in dynamic variable